# Spring 2 Hibernate Annotation

Tags: hibernate, spring, annotations

I am setting up Hibernate Annotation (User JPA for mapping) with Spring. (i.e. AnnotationSessionFactoryBean)

I have a few questions

1. Do I need a hibernate.cfg.xml for mapping?
2. From the example http://www.zabada.com/tutorials/hibernate-and-jpa-with-spring-example.php, it seems you need to do AOP, do you really need that? I saw a lot of example doesn't have that?

Is there any good tutorial around the web?

Thanks
Roy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The annotations drive the mapping so you don't need the mapping file as well.
2. I use Spring & Hibernate without AOP so i don't think it's required.

There's a rather terse tutorial [here](http://stsmedia.net/spring-finance-part-3-ddd-jpa-transaction-support/). It's using Spring 3 but i don't think that affects the JPA stuff.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I think I did something stupid, I redo the whole thing from scratch and it works now